# How can I properly add PostGIS data into MapGuide Maestro?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, mapguide, postgis-1.5

I am having trouble connecting a PostGIS database to MapGuide Maestro. Actually, I have added the PostGIS data into Maestro, but when I click to validate the layer it shows an error message:

`Validating resource: Session:9754d026-d86b-11e1-8000-00270e208411_en_7F0000010AFC0AFB0AFA//259f852d-fc68-4475-9de1-a5e446fb6e82.FeatureSource
Warning - OSGeo.MapGuide.ObjectModels.FeatureSource_1_0_0.FeatureSourceType: Spatial context extent appears to be invalid (or is the default extent returned by FDO provider. Meaning it very likely does not truly represent the extent of your data)
Information - OSGeo.MapGuide.ObjectModels.FeatureSource_1_0_0.FeatureSourceType: No primary key defined for class: public:geography_columns, features will not be selectable and feature joins on this class may produce unexpected results`

Can anyone please suggest where I went wrong? **Is there any documentation for how to add PostGIS data into MapGuide Maestro?**

Also, if I click to see the preview of the layer it gives me an error report of `Fusion Error`.

I am using PostgreSQL 8.4, PostGIS 1.5, MapGuide 2.2 and MapGuide Maestro 4.01

Thanks in advance..

Comment: It looks like you need to make sure that your postgis setup is working correctly first. Run some tests?

Comment: By keeping coordinate system as default in both map definition and also in application definition the `Fusion Error` can be stoped.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect the Postgres database table to MapGuide?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30624/how-to-connect-the-postgres-database-table-to-mapguide)